# Getting Error Cannot find module 'q' on Build of multi device hybrid app in Visual Studio 2013 Update 3

Tags: visual-studio-2013, multi-device-hybrid-apps

the question was asked before, but the solution did not Change anything for me. I had Problems connecting to my Android device so I reinstalled the CTP2 of Multi device hybrid apps. Now the Build process is not working any more. I get the following errors on a new blank solution:

Error 2 Cannot find module 'q'  D:\TFS\W1\trunk...\EXEC 1 1 BlankCordovaAppHelloWorld

Error   3   The command ""C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda\vs-cli" prepare --platform Android --configuration Debug --projectDir . --projectName "BlankCordovaAppHelloWorld" --language "en-US"" exited with code 8. C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.targets   182 5   BlankCordovaAppHelloWorld

I already restored the System to a restore Point and reinstalled everything over and over but without success....???

Kind regards,
Markus

Edit:
I I try to install ripple manually I get the following warning (I don't know if this means that the install failed or not)

npm WARN engine ripple@0.1.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"0.10.30","npm":"1.4.21"}) C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\ripple -> C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple\ripple.js ripple@0.1.1 C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ripple
├── commander@0.5.2
└── colors@0.6.2

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477665/cannot-create-new-project-vs2013-and-multi-hybrid-device-app/25514980#25514980)?  You will need to uninstall your vs-mda and vs-mda-targets and then reinstall them specifying the full path to those folders under the visual studio installation folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to uninstall your vs-mda and vs-mda-targets and then reinstall them specifying the full path to those folders under the visual studio installation folder.

Source: [Cannot create new project (VS2013 and multi-hybrid device app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477665/cannot-create-new-project-vs2013-and-multi-hybrid-device-app/25514980#25514980)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using java JDK x64 (including JRE), Visaul Studio 2015 in Windows 7 x64, my solution: uninstall NodeJS x86 then reboot, install NodeJS x64 and then it worked!