# VS2013 Apache Cardova Cannot find module 'q'

Tags: javascript, c#, android, mobile, visual-studio-2013

I created a Blank CardovaApp in VisualStudio2013 Updated with update 4.
as I run it for a test with 'Android Emulator' then bug occurs with

**Cannot find module 'q'**

im using a W8.1 machine x64 with 8gb of ram.
any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should need to build with new cordova CLI method hope it will works.

Comment: You may find answer here for the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477665/cannot-create-new-project-vs2013-and-multi-hybrid-device-app/25514980#25514980