# error 404 Not Found: vs-mda

Tags: windows, node.js, cordova

I tried to solve similar problem to:
[Cannot create new project (VS2013 and multi-hybrid device app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25477665/cannot-create-new-project-vs2013-and-multi-hybrid-device-app)
but I can not install vs-mda or vs-mda-target.
Please help!

```
28 verbose cwd C:\Users\admin\Documents\test
29 error Windows_NT 6.3.9600
30 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "-g" "install" "vs-mda"
31 error node v0.12.0
32 error npm  v2.5.1
33 error code E404
34 error 404 Not Found: vs-mda
34 error 404
34 error 404 'vs-mda' is not in the npm registry.
34 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
34 error 404
34 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
34 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
35 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER for problem for VisualStudio 2013 CommunityEdition: download Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova CTP3.1 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675